# Draw overlay on iOS Camera and Save image with Overlay

Tags: ios, tesseract, ios-camera

I'm trying to Implement tesseract Ocr for Car Engine VIN number reader. Partially I have done it with the help of tesseract ocr sdk. Now I'm trying to implement camera something like this [image]
I would like to do any of these three,

1. crop the image automatically inside rectangle
2. capture the image only inside rectangle
3. save image along with rectangle overlay.
   I'm sorry, I'm new to iOS development. kindly help me. Thank you.

Comment: check this guide.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: @RathaKrishna: Did you get solution for this?

Comment: @RamRaj- Any solution for this